# Domain Availability check in php

Tags: php

I used [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) for checking domain availability. Its work fine, but after certain time period it always return false. Anyone can give me solution for this problem or suggest me alternate way to check availability of domain.

```
if (gethostbyname($domain) == $domain) {
    return true;
 }
else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Its possible to register a domain and not create DNS records for it ...

Comment: Use NameCheap API https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/domains/check.aspx

Comment: @DaveChen question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone can give me solution for this problem or suggest me alternate way to check availability of domain.

Sure. Use an API of a trusted domain seller. For example, Namecheap.

- Signup to their API: https://www.sandbox.namecheap.com/myaccount/signup.aspx?
- Read their documentation on checking domain availability: https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/domains/check.aspx
- [Enable API access](https://manage.www.sandbox.namecheap.com/myaccount/modify-profile-api.asp)
- Create a CURL request to their endpoint

  - Or `file_get_contents`, but it's not advised, unless you `allow_url_fopen`
- Interpret the response

#### Why?

- It's more reliable than `gethostbyname()`
- You only need to make a CURL call, and don't need to bother about all the technical behind the scenes stuff
- The results are given by a trusted domain seller
- It's fully documented and updated
- *Who doesn't like using APIs?*

#### Useful links

- [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) to send requests
- [simplexml](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) to interpret the response

Answer (score 2):

`gethostbyname()` does not check the availability of a domain name. It attempts to perform a DNS lookup, which may sometimes fail even when the domain is registered.

If you want to check domain availability, you will need to set up an account with an appropriate domain reseller, then use their API.